# Getting " Could not determine repository generation from root blobs" while creating snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch

Creating snapshots throws " Could not determine repository generation from root blobs" error after updating access key and secret key

This is the script i used for updating creds

```
for pod in $(kubectl get pods -o=name | grep elasticsearch |  grep -v exporter | sed "s/^.\{4\}//")
do
    kubectl exec -t $pod \
          -- /bin/bash -c "echo $1 | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.access_key && echo $2 | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force s3.client.default.secret_key"
       echo $pod
    done
```

invoked by sh updatekey.sh

PUT request create snapshot

```
PUT /_snapshot/test_es/test_snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "test*",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```

while running this i am getting this following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[test_es] Could not determine repository generation from root blobs"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_exception",
    "reason": "[test_es] Could not determine repository generation from root blobs",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Exception when listing blobs by prefix [index-]",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "sdk_client_exception",
        "reason": "sdk_client_exception: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Not sure whats wrong.. any help is much appriciated